# wait for request to finish and return data

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, q

I'm building an Restful API with node js this is my code

There are 3 main parts, I created a get method that has to return some data

the get calls getImportIoData that has a request to an external API and this method calls another method called getEmailFromWebSite this other method calls another request, 
how can I wait for every request to finish an return data

I Know this has been answered in other questions but I tried some of them and didn't work

I tried Async and q libraries, also the callback on this part Doesn't work

> ```
> if (item.website !== undefined){
>               getEmailFromWebSite(item.website, function(email){console.log(email); item.email = email;});
>             }
> ```

I don't know If Im doing something wrong,

Can someone help me with this? using my code

Thanks in advance

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var Type = req.query.Type;
  var Locations = req.query.Locations;
  var Page = req.query.Page;
  res.send(getImportIoData(res, Type, Locations, Page));
});

function getImportIoData(res, Type, Locations, Page) {
  var criteria = {
    'search_terms': Type,
    'geo_location_terms': Locations,
    'page': Page
  }
  var url = consts.import_io + consts.import_key + consts.query +
    encodeURIComponent(consts.api_url) + encodeQueryData(criteria) +
    /*"&_user=" + consts.user + */"&_apikey=" + consts.api_key;

  request(url, function(error, response, json) {
    var data = JSON.parse(json);
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      var doctors = _.forEach(data.results, function(item) {
        if (item.website !== undefined){
          getEmailFromWebSite(item.website, function(email){console.log(email); item.email = email;});
        }
      });
      return data.results
    }
    //else 
  });
}

function getEmailFromWebSite(website, callback) {

  var EmptyReturn='';
  searchTerm = extractDomain(website).replace('www.', '');
  if (searchTerm != ''){
    var EH_APIURL = 'https://api.emailhunter.co/v1/search?domain='+searchTerm+'&api_key='+ consts.EmailHunterAPIKey;

    request(EH_APIURL, function(error, response, json) {
      var data = JSON.parse(json);
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        if((data.emails).length != 0){
          var Emailobject = data.emails;
          var EmailString = returnEmails(Emailobject);
          callback(EmailString);
        }else
          callback(EmptyReturn);
      }else if (response.statusCode === 429)
        console.log('The number of Request has been Reached for this account');
      else if (response.statusCode > 500)
        console.log('Error with Email Hunter Servers');
      else
        console.log('An Error Ocurred');
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no code related to `q` in there but `q.all` receives an array of promises and resolves when all of those promises are resolved, so you can do something like this..

```
var promises = [ promiseOne(), promiseTwo(), promiseThree() ];
q.all(promises).then(function(results) {
    //results is an array with the resolution values from all your promises in the order you specified in the promises array
});
```

Comment: is there a way for you to use my code for this example, it is because, I don't get this example